# how to append a 1d numpy array to a 2d numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy, append

I would like to append an array [3, 3, 3] to an array [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], so that it becomes [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], 
                 [2, 2, 2]])

arr2 = np.append(arr1, [3, 3, 3])

print (arr2)
```

instead of printing `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]`,

it prints `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`.

I am quite new to numpy and I do not understand why the 2d array suddenly becomes 1d.

Comment: Did you go back and read the `np.append` docs?  It explains the flattening.

Comment: Yes, it says you have to use the parameter ``axis=0``` . I tried doing that with: ```arr2 = np.append(arr1, [3, 3, 3], axis=0)``` and it gives me the error: ```all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)```

Comment: `np.append` is basically an alternate way of calling `np.concatenate`, as the traceback to your error shows.  One array is (2,3) shape, the other (3,).  The 2nd should be (1,3) shape to concatenate.  `vstack` is an alternative user of `concatenate` that takes care of that detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the useful `numpy`'s standard method of `vstack`.

Here is my code.

**Initialize 2-dimensional numpy array**

```
initial_array = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1], 
    [2, 2, 2]
])
```

**define the array to append to initiali array**

```
new_array = np.array([3, 3, 3])
```

**append the new array to initial array as row**

```
result = np.vstack((initial_array, new_array))
```

**this is the result**

```
print(result)
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

You can read more details at [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-add-row-columns-in-numpy-array/).

Hope this answer to be helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], 
                 [2, 2, 2]])

arr2 = np.append(arr1, [[3, 3, 3]], axis=0)

print (arr2)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [2 2 2]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [3 3 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
arr2 = np.vstack((arr1, [3,3,3]))
>>> arr2
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]
```